# Save Configurable Products automatically

Tags: configurable-product, cron, simple-product, save

My configurable product prices are updated with Lowest Price simple product on Save.

As I have thousands of configurable products I can't manually open and save all of them.

Is there any way I can Open/Save all configurable products with a cron/script etc.

Answer (score 0):

**To get only configurable products (since you need to update PRICE) below is the code:**

```
$configurableProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                          ->getCollection()
                          ->joinAttribute(
                                        'price',
                                        'catalog_product/price',
                                        'entity_id',
                                        null,
                                        'left',
                                        1 //key in your store id which I am guessing to be '1'
                                      );

$configurableProducts->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 4);
```

**To save each configurable product below is the code:**

```
foreach ($configurableProducts as $_product)
{
   Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->save(); 
   //This is not the best practice to load Model inside a FOREACH loop. However, this is going to be a standalone SCRIPT.
}
```

Quickest / Simplest script.

Happy Coding...

Comment: The prices are not updating. Im using [This](https://github.com/QVCItalia/magento-configurable-auto-pricing) to change the configurable product price on save